# Setting up GLEW and GLFW in VS Code with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-code, glfw, glew, cl

I have a basic Visual C++ environment in Visual Studio Code. I've recently started to read about OpenGL and have been trying to set up GLEW and GLFW in VS Code. Almost all of the tutorials I find fall into one of the 2 categories:

1. GLEW and GLFW setup with MSVC, but in Visual Studio.
2. GLEW and GLFW setup in VS Code, but with minGW.

I've read the documentation for MSVC command line and its options a few times and can't figure it out. I'm not familiar with Cmake and such, so I've been trying to do it via VS Code *tasks.json* file.

[image: Directory structure]

My *tasks.json* file is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [

        // BUILD TASK
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: build project",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                // exception handling args
                "/EHsc",
                // including additional headers
                "/I${workspaceFolder}\\include\\glew\\include",
                "/I${workspaceFolder}\\include\\glfw\\include",
                // obj files path
                "/Fo${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\",
                // exe file path
                "/Fe:", "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\program.exe", 
                // source files
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
                // library files
                "opengl32.lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\include\\glew\\lib\\Release\\x64\\glew32s.lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\include\\glfw\\lib-vc2019\\glfw3.lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },

        // CLEAN TASK
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clean project",
            "command": "del",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\*",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

And my *main.cpp* file has a few lines of code to open a window.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 700, "Test window 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open GLFW window" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Full terminal output while running build task at this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aGaEQtCg)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently and solved it by using the dlls, instead of static linking

For this, you'd add `glfw3dll.lib` instead of `glfw3.lib` (which you should have in the same zip you've downloaded from glfw website, alongside the dll) and place the dll nearby the executable.

You should also define `GLFW_DLL` before including any other glfw headers, as the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html) states

Answer (score 1):

Right I am using MinGW as the compiler and after many days trying to fix this problem my self I found that this works.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KROm0.png)

For the task file you need to put (in the args in the task json for vs code):

```
"-g",
"-std=c++17",
"${file}",
"-I",
"./include",
"-L",
"./lib",
"-lopengl32",
"-lglew32",
"-lglfw3dll",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

Then it should work. Side note you also need glfw3.dll with glew32.dll